# Java Regex exclude one line in bloc address

Tags: java, regex, matching

This is my regex pattern :

```
\b(?!(?i)Doctor| )([^\s]*\b)[\n\r\s]+(\b[\S\s][^\d]*\b)[\s\S]+([0-9]{5})\s+([\D]*)
```

I need to retrieve the differents informations in bloc address, ex :

```
Doctor John DOE
123 dream road 
12345 TOWN
```

Java Code:

```
firstName = matcher.group(1).trim();
lastName = matcher.group(2).trim();
```

It works fine ! But sometimes there are an additional line :

```
Doctor John DOE
Country Hospital
123 dream road 
12345 TOWN
```

Firstname is well retrieved: "John"
but the lastname retrieved is "DOE Country Hospital"

The ideal aim would be to get firstname, lastname, address line 1 (if present....), Address line 2, Code and town in separate field.

but I don't find the correct pattern...

**EDIT: java code**
[image]

Comment: [Design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) do not relate to regular expressions.

Comment: Replace `[^\d]` with `[^\n\r\d]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `[\s\S]` and instead use `.` if you don't want to capture newlines too. Usage of `[\s\S]` is leading to capturing of `DOE Country Hospital` because there is a newline after `DOE` and `[\s\S]` will capture that newline but `.` won't unless you use `(?s)` modifier which makes `.` to capture newline too.

With the two examples you have in your post, where first line of address is optional, you can use following regex to capture different parts in your address. I have simplified your regex and used `\R` to match a newline as `\R` matches almost all variants of newlines in various operating systems.

```
^(?:(?i)Doctor )?(?<FirstName>\S+)\s+(?<LastName>\S+)(?:\R(?<AddressLine1>.+))?\R(?:(?<AddressLine2>.+))\R(?<Code>\d{5})\s+(?<Town>.+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9nDatf/1)

Notice, I have used named groups to make it easy to spot what is what. You can remove it and make the regex shorter. Let me know if this works for you and I will add explanation as you need.

Edit for working Java code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = "^(?:(?i)Doctor )?(?<FirstName>\\S+)\\s+(?<LastName>\\S+)(?:\\R(?<AddressLine1>.+))?\\R(?:(?<AddressLine2>.+))\\R(?<Code>\\d{5})\\s+(?<Town>.+)$";
    final String string = "Doctor John DOE\n"
 + "123 dream road \n"
 + "12345 TOWN\n\n\n"
 + "Doctor John DOE\n"
 + "Country Hospital\n"
 + "123 dream road \n"
 + "12345 TOWN";
    
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group()+ "\n");
        System.out.println("Group FirstName: " + matcher.group("FirstName"));
        System.out.println("Group LastName: " + matcher.group("LastName"));
        System.out.println("Group AddressLine1: " + matcher.group("AddressLine1"));
        System.out.println("Group AddressLine2: " + matcher.group("AddressLine2"));
        System.out.println("Group Code: " + matcher.group("Code"));
        System.out.println("Group Town: " + matcher.group("Town"));
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
}
```

And this produces following output,

```
Full match: Doctor John DOE
123 dream road 
12345 TOWN

Group FirstName: John
Group LastName: DOE
Group AddressLine1: null
Group AddressLine2: 123 dream road 
Group Code: 12345
Group Town: TOWN



Full match: Doctor John DOE
Country Hospital
123 dream road 
12345 TOWN

Group FirstName: John
Group LastName: DOE
Group AddressLine1: Country Hospital
Group AddressLine2: 123 dream road 
Group Code: 12345
Group Town: TOWN
```

Comment: It doesn't work: i copy paste your regex and update it for java code : \\ instead of \

Comment: Can you show me your java code? Most likely some silly mistake.

Comment: Attaching image for code isn't a good idea as one can't copy paste and try at their end. Also I can't see what is the input string you are trying to parse using regex. Updating my answer with sample java code, which works exactly like you want. Seems your input data has some unexpected things you haven't disclosed.

Comment: sorry, i did like that to show you : code, input text and output result. My input text come from an extraction of a pdf file. So I test your code in real condition

Comment: May be you should extract the text from pdf to a text file and check on regex101 to see if its matching or not. Most likely the text you are trying to parse is not same as you indicated in your post. There is something different in your actual pdf text due to which match is failing.

Comment: I try your code and I found why it doesn't work with extracted text: there is a space character after the LastName

Comment: In that case just put a `\\s*` after the lastname part in regex

Comment: @anakin59490: If it all worked out for you then you should consider accepting this answer.